# How to deactivate image_transport plugins?

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I would like to deactivate image_transport plugins from a launch file. My robot has many cameras and I am not using the compressed images. It would save CPU time if I can do that. I would prefer a solution involving a launch file since other members of my team may use those compressed images. If you have no solution with a launch file, I am open to any suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Stanley

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255970/how-to-deactivate-image_transport-plugins?/) by [Stanley666](https://answers.ros.org/users/29533/stanley666/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-17**:
I'm going to take a look at adding this feature to image_transport.  Though I believe in your case the compression is not actually performed unless there is a subscriber on that topic, so there shouldn't be much cpu load (but it still would be nice to disable undesired plugins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common hydro-devel branch now has
[a disabling plugins feature merged in](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/pull/60):

```
rosparam set /camera/image/disable_pub_plugins "['image_transport/compressedDepth', 'image_transport/theora']"
rosrun image_transport_tutorial my_publisher
```

And also the launch file equivalent:

```
<node name="my_publisher" pkg="image_transport_tutorial" type="my_publisher" />
<group ns="camera/image" >
  <rosparam param="disable_pub_plugins">
    - 'image_transport/compressedDepth'
    - 'image_transport/theora'
  </rosparam>
</group>
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2019-12-04**:
Hi there, this might be a silly question, but is this working on ros-kinetic?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-12-04**:
I just tested it in kinetic on ubuntu 16.04
and it does work.  Most likely there is a mismatch between your actual image topic and the namespace you are setting `disable_pub_plugins` in.

**Comment by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on 2020-07-10**:
you can also just uninstall the unnecessary image_transport pluggins like:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-melodic-theora-image-transport
sudo apt-get remove ros-melodic-compressed-image-transport
sudo apt-get remove ros-melodic-compressed-image-transport
```

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-05-18**:
@lucasw where i must put the first few lines of your solution, sorry I dont get it. I found only the header files and changed the commits there, but cant find the image_transport.cpp and the publisher.cpp. Would be glad if you can help me with that

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-05-19**:
You need to set the `disable_pub_plugins` list parameter in the namespace of your camera, in my example above the namespace is `camera/image`.  Probably you want to set in your launch file, you shouldn't have to change any header or cpp files.

At some point I'll add a dynamic reconfigure solution so they can be toggled on and off live.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-05-20**:
thank you for your answer, so i miss probably the namespace just use rosparam. sound good with the option to switch it manually :)